# Tomcat waiting for join jgroups cluster

Tags: java, ehcache, jgroups

I uses EHCache + JGroups to replicate the cache of my webapps on 3 tomcat instances.

```
<!-- Use jgroups (UDP) to replicate cache among the cluster -->
    <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
properties="channelName=EH_CACHE_STA::connect=UDP(mcast_addr=229.10.10.10;mcast_port=45567;):PING:MERGE2:FD_SOCK:VERIFY_SUSPECT:pbcast.NAKACK:UNICAST:pbcast.STABLE:FRAG:pbcast.GMS"
        propertySeparator="::" />
```

Sometimes a tomcat instance don't restart. In the jgroups logs I can see :

```
[webapp] WARN  2012-12-14 15:36:55,784 [GMS] : join(tc-fr-sta-tomcat1-32427) sent to b0dc40aa-12aa-4045-01e4-c80b013dbb13 timed out (after 5000 ms), retrying
[webapp] WARN  2012-12-14 15:36:55,785 [UDP] : tc-fr-sta-tomcat1-32427: no physical address for b0dc40aa-12aa-4045-01e4-c80b013dbb13, dropping message
```

It seems the node try to join himself ???!
We have to restart all tomcat in production to restore the cluster.
Anybody can help me to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of JGroups is this running with (java -jar jgroups.jar) ? I recommend to run with the latest stable version. Also, set timer_type="old" in UDP.

In addition, it would be better if ehcache allowed for a JGroups config to be defined in an XML file, perhaps the latest version does this ? (I'm not an ehcache expert).
Cheers,
Bela

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the timer_type="old" parameter in the UDP config. Here my jgroups version : Version:      2.10.0.GA
CVS:          $Id: Version.java,v 1.101 2010/07/12 11:34:27 belaban Exp $

Comment: can help in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568661/face-clustering-in-tomcat-6-on-multiple-machine